# Pandas take value from columns if not NaN

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['One','Two',np.nan],
                   'B':[np.nan,np.nan,'Three'],
                   })
df

    A       B
0   One     NaN
1   Two     NaN
2   NaN     Three
```

I'd like to create one column ('C') that takes the value of either 'A' or 'B' if it is not NaN like this:

```
    A       B        C
0   One     NaN      One
1   Two     NaN      Two
2   NaN     Three    Three
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
df['C'] = df.A.combine_first(df.B)
print df                   
     A      B      C
0  One    NaN    One
1  Two    NaN    Two
2  NaN  Three  Three
```

Or [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['C']= df.A.fillna(df.B)
print df                   
     A      B      C
0  One    NaN    One
1  Two    NaN    Two
2  NaN  Three  Three
```

Or [np.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and add value if both conditions are False e.g. 1:

```
df['C'] = np.where(df.A.notnull(), df.A,np.where(df.B.notnull(), df.B, 1))
print df                   
     A      B      C
0  One    NaN    One
1  Two    NaN    Two
2  NaN  Three  Three
```